1) A dictionary says "on a weekend" is a British informal phrase. Is it so? 2) "On the weekend of" is used in US and "at the weekend of" in UK, right?
As I understood, "at" is used with "weekend" in UK and "on" in US.
But there are some examples in a dictionary that confused me.

oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com:

on a weekend (British English, informal):
(1a) I like to go out on a weekend.

Googling "on a weekend" led me to the conclusion that it is not used in UK (as the dictionary says) and it can be used only in US but some American native speakers consider it unnatural. So, seeing it in a dictionary as an example of British English confused me very much.
my variant:
(1b) I like to go out at a weekend.
Am I right that:
– (1a) is used not in UK but in US although some American speakers consider it unnatural?
– (1b) is used in UK although some British speakers consider it unnatural?
If not, then why not?

oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com:

on the weekend of:
(2a) It happened on the weekend of 24 and 25 April.

my variant:
(2b) It happened at the weekend of 24 and 25 April.
Am I right that:
– since "on" is in (2a), hence (1a) is how people usually speak in US?
– since "at" is in (2b), hence (1b) is how people usually speak in UK?
If not, then why not?

You are mistaken. The phrase 'on a weekend' is very common and normal in UK English and also  US English. Nobody, ever, in either kind of English, says 'at a weekend'

I think AmE might favor on the weekend.

"on weekends" is also common for the general (not a specific weekend). Seems to be both UK and US.

Britannica says "at the weekend" is UK only, while Americans prefer "on". Have a look at that link.

In BrE "I like to go out at the weekend" is the same as "I like to go out on a weekend", with meaning "I generally like to ...", rather than on a specific weekend. For that 2a is correct and 2b definitely wrong.

Related questions: on/at, weekends/the weekend, on the weekend, in/on

The US on/British at (the weekend) split is just a tendency. Either side can use either. Things are pretty busy for Theresa, what with her daughter, Grace (Abby Quinn), getting married at the weekend, but she makes time for Isabel, who sits down and launches into her pitch about the youthful poor of India. Review of a 2019 film ('After the Wedding') in The New Yorker. Weekend working refers to the practice of working on the weekend. In the UK, Saturdays and Sundays aren’t typically considered ‘working days’. Rocket Lawyer Ltd (London EC2A 4NE)

The main difference between BrE and AmE is that the Brits use at and on, whereas AmE uses only on.

@Lambie - except at the New Yorker?

@MichaelHarvey AmE generally does not say at weekend, but a New Yorker editor would leave it as totally acceptable as AmE and BrE writers write for them. Take a look at the author of that article. Also, AmE snobs might use it on purpose, just like I use certain British expressions like "crack on".

Oh dear, this is the kind of answer that awakens trolls. Few native speakers can authoritatively say what is correct in both dialects - especially as there is much variation even within the two. I've tried to address the fact that both phrases appear in British English so it isn't that the two are just American and British equivalents. It looks like the same might be true in American English but perhaps with some variation in the usage.

:@Astralbee - this is a recurring thing (people being dogmatic about what BrE/AmE users do or don't say).

@Lambie - fair enough, but I found one author from 'working class suburbs of Boston (Mass)'.

At the weekend is a British English expression, which is used the same way as on the weekend in American English. Speakers of American English may understand this expression, but they do not use it. https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/eb/qa/Over-the-weekend-on-the-weekend-at-the-weekend#:~:text=At%20the%20weekend%20is%20a,they%20do%20not%20use%20it. I don't know why one would pussyfoot around with this. Satisfied?

@Lambie - it's a tendency, not an absolute rule.

@MichaelHarvey No, it is only used in American English by Anglophiles. I know because my father was one. He ordered books from Blackwells, (when we lived in Brazil!)  had a picture of Winston Churchill on the wall behind the glass door of his office, and chewed out a maid for not following his instructions on how to properly heat the teapot before letting the tea steep. In all my years (and they are many!) of living in the states after 15 years in France, I have never heard an American say "at the weekend". I live in the NE near Boston which looks just like a British village.

@Lambie - 'crack on' is distinctly demotic in Britain, so an aspiring American snob surely ought to find something else to slip into their conversations?

I'm British, and I don't claim to know if there is a difference in any other dialect such as American English, but there is a clear difference between the uses of "on a weekend" and "on the weekend" in similar contexts.

We'd use "on the weekend" if referring to either a specific weekend (one that is the obvious subject or has been previously mentioned) or to refer to every weekend, like something habitual. For example, "I'm going camping on the weekend" implies the upcoming weekend, or the weekend of a particular week that has already been mentioned, and "I like to spend time with my family on the weekend" suggests the speaker does that every weekend as a habit.

"On a weekend" is more general and doesn't necessarily refer to a specific weekend. It's used when discussing activities or events that could happen on any weekend, but not necessarily every weekend. For example, "I like to relax and unwind on a weekend" suggests a general preference but there is no surety that always happens.


As they are both used in British English and have different uses and implications I can't entirely agree that one is favoured in BrEng and the other in AmEng, but other dialects may prefer other phrases like "at weekends" (which British speakers also use) to refer to weekends in a more general sense.

This on a weekend, on the weekend is the same in AmE. No difference at all. The difference is in the generic, at weekends versus on weekends. Another is that AmE doesn't really use: at the weekend like Brits.

In the U.S. on the weekend means on some weekends.   In the U.S. on the weekend does not refer to a specific weekend unless additional context is supplied.  On the weekend we spent at the cabin, we went canoeing.

@EllieK so that's no different then. We'd supply context too, but it doesn't have to be in the same sentence.
